Terraform AWS SES deployment Issue
I ma trying to deploy AWS SES Service through Terraform. Here is my main.tf block.
I am using existing domain and zone_id in route 53
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "domain_identity" {
 domain = var.my_domain #domain already exists
  }


resource "aws_ses_domain_dkim" "dkim_domain" {
  domain = aws_ses_domain_identity.domain_identity.domain
}



resource "aws_route53_record" "ses_verification" {
  depends_on = [ aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain ]
  zone_id = var.zone_id #Existing zone_id
  name = "_amazonaws.qa.com"
  type = "TXT"
  ttl = 600
  records = [aws_ses_domain_identity.domain_identity.verification_token]
}



resource "aws_route53_record" "ses_dkim_record" {
  depends_on = [ aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain ]
  count = length(aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain.dkim_tokens)
  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name = element(aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain.dkim_tokens, count.index)
  type = "CNAME"
  ttl = 600
  records = [concat(element(aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain.dkim_tokens, count.index),".amazonses.com")]
}

While running Terraform apply, I am getting below error:
╷
│ Error: Invalid count argument
│ 
│   on ses/main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_route53_record" "ses_dkim_record":
│   30:   count = length(aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain.dkim_tokens)
│ 
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
│ until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be
│ created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only
│ the resources that the count depends on.
╵
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

I am deploying SES for the first time so not sure where it is failing.
Thank You

I think you have to use for_each instead of count for this.

According to the documentation, "count can't refer to any resource attributes that aren't known until after a configuration is applied". So you have to apply the aws_ses_domain_dkim.dkim_domain resource before you can refer to it in a count and make this file a two-stage apply.
You could use the method mentioned in the error "To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on" or comment out the ses_dkim_record on your first apply.
Looking at the for_each documentation may provide an alternative solution.
